# firefox URL autocomplete: how to suppress autocomplete for the first few characters?

Tags: firefox, awesomebar

Firefox's "awesomebar" goes into autocomplete mode as soon as you type in 1 character. That seems silly to me, and it hangs for a few seconds when I first start the program up, as it does its thinking + database queries / caching / whatever.

Is there a way I can suppress autocomplete until at least 3 or 4 characters have been typed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the '`search.timeout`' configuration (in `Sean`'s answer),
[a few more suggestions here](http://ed.agadak.net/2009/02/firefox-31-location-bar-preferences) and [here](http://blog.ro-design.net/index.php/2008/06/18/how-to-revert-to-the-firefox-2-autocomplete-location-bar-settings-in-firefox-3.html) might make your experience better.

You may want to look at,

- '`browser.urlbar.default.behavior`'
- '`browser.urlbar.matchBehavior`'

Comment: aha, the default behavior is something that looks really promising. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to "vacuum" the database Firefox uses to store your history - believe it or not, it *greatly* improves the speed of the awesome bar.

There are two ways to do this - manually, or through an extension.

Manually:

1. Open the Error Console - Tools->Error Console (on a Windows computer, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>)
2. In the Code box, paste the following line (it's one line):

   `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsPIPlacesDatabase).DBConnection.executeSimpleSQL("VACUUM");`
3. Press the Evaluate button. Firefox will seem to "hang" as it cleans up the database.
4. You're done!

Extension: [Vacuum Places](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13824) - after it's installed, just click on the little vacuum in the status bar, and it cleans everything up!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a setting to set the minimum characters required to launch a search, but you can try increasing the [searchTimeout](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.search.timeout) setting to, say, 700 (ms) from the default of 100. This will give you a chance to type a few more characters before the thrashing begins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to configure autocomplete in the Firefox 3 AwesomeBar.

**However**, I find that the [oldbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6227) extension works great.  It restores the old the Location Bar functionality of Firefox 2 to Firefox 3